# Determining UAC requirements for legacy .net 1.1 application

Tags: asp.net, uac

We have inherited an old .net 1.1  Asp.net application which, in the installation guide, requires UAC  (User Account Control) to be switched off.

We have access to the source code but the original developers have long since gone.

Can the panel suggest reasons as to why the application may need this feature of windows switched off please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what the application is doing.  It could be accessing parts of the registry, or WMI, or the root of a disk, or the Windows folder, error logs, services database, etc.

You'll probably need to have a developer look through the code to see what it does.